# A lone 連用形 in song lyrics

Tags: grammar, song-lyrics, renyōkei

The [lyrics](https://utaten.com/lyric/ac18071012/) to 魅惑劇 by ALI PROJECT contain the following fragment:

> 叶わぬ願いは過去のもの
> 愛する痛みは**傷を閉じ**
> 魅惑劇

I would take the bolded 閉じ to be either continuative or a nominalization, except in the first case there isn't any verb that the sentence/statement could continue onto (is it perhaps just an artistic omission?) and as for the second I haven't really encountered 閉じ used to mean 閉じること searching around on the web. I'm also not sure whether it could be used with を in such a case.
Is it one of the things listed or something else entirely? What nuance does it carry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is continuative, i.e., so-called 連用中止 (e.g. [here](https://nihongokyoshi-net.com/2018/12/06/jlptn3-grammar-renyoochuushi/)). A general effect is usually explained as '余韻を残す' (giving an impression/aftereffect), but here I suppose it can be considered simply for connecting to the third line.

A reason should be metric. Note that the first and the second line use the same number of syllables (hiraganas).

> 叶わぬ願いは (8) 過去のもの (5)
> 愛する痛みは (8) 傷を閉じ (5)

Looking at the lyrics, other parts seem to have a distinct pattern for the number of syllables as well (I didn't count, so could be wrong).